# Simplest way to process HTTP post data in C++

Tags: html, c++, http, post, webserver

I would like a website to send data to be stored to a database. Consequently I think I require a web server, listening to HTTP, parsing the POST, extracting the data and storing to database?

I'd like the web server to be C++.

However, I am struggling to find a simple example. I assume this is simple because we're just listening to a TCP socket and once all the data has been received, it's just a string parsing exercise? All the examples I can find seem way-over complicated. For example:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/beast/example/http/server/async/http_server_async.cpp

Surely it shouldn't require 300-400 lines just to listen to a socket and parse a string?

Is my understanding wrong/is there a simple way to process a HTTP POST in C++?

Comment: Send data where?

Comment: The formal specification for RFC 2616 runs to almost 200 pages of text. You can't expect to implement all of that in a few dozen lines of code. Even for a minimal subset to handle a basic POST request, a few hundred lines of code sounds about right.

Comment: Listen to a socket, no. Parse a string, depends on how complicated the language is. Handle all of the cases that crop up while parsing the string, that can be hell.  Remember that done right simply reading a number from `cin` and handling all of the error cases can take a dozen or more lines of code. And you still haven't gotten to performing the POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing your own web server in C++ that

- only supports a single HTTP connection from a single client at a time,
- assumes that the incoming HTTP requests are never malformed and always in a certain format, and always of a certain type,
- in the case of something unexpected happening, is not required to provide a proper HTTP response,

would not be too hard. However, if you want your web server to be fully [HTTP/1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) or [HTTP/3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/3) compliant, then writing such a server would be a lot of work, as those standards are dozens or even hundreds of pages long.

It would probably be more meaningful to use existing HTTP server software, such as [Apache HTTP Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server), and write your own programs that are designed to serve individual HTTP requests, and to configure the server to call these programs for certain URLs. That way, you won't have to deal with most of the details of HTTP, but you will still have to deal with HTTP requests and HTTP responses.

Some scripting languages such as [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) (which is designed to run on a web server) handle most of the remaining HTTP details for you, so you for example don't have to worry much about interpreting the HTTP request header and creating a HTTP response header. These scripting languages generally also allow you to connect to an external database server.

If you don't want to use a scripting language, but would prefer for the individual HTTP requests to be handled by programs written in C++, then this is possible too, for example using [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) or an API provided by the HTTP server software.

Comment: Ah thank you. I didn't realise I can use something like Apache and write a C++ module. I require C++ for the performance and also to generate binary data from the POST and send to another process.

Comment: @mezamorphic: I recommend that you first try [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) for testing purposes, since that is the simplest interface for your C++ program to the web server. However, since you state that performance is the main issue, I suggest that you don't stick to CGI in the long run, but instead explore the more efficient alternatives mentioned in the linked Wikipedia article on CGI.

Comment: @mezamorphic: In the long run, of particular interest to you will probably be [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI). If you are using Apache HTTP Server, then you will probably be using [mod_fcgid](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/) for FastCGI.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use restbed library which is work with c++14. Very easy to use in cases like yours. It is very up to your string but I guess you can solve your issue with 50 lines most. With this library it is very easy to handle post requests. You can implement your handlers as a function and give them to library as a method handler. Documentation of library : https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/blob/master/documentation/API.md?ysclid=l4ny6wicl231191828

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).